# Error in compilation when using kotlin and retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Hi im new with retrofit and im having some problems, when i click in the button the application stop working, when i debugged the program stop working this part
         service.Lists().enqueue(object : Callback>{

this is my code, thanks

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val btn  = findViewById(R.id.btnPresentacion) as Button

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        val wordtest = findViewById(R.id.LblPresentacion) as TextView

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create<ApiService>(ApiService::class.java)


        service.Lists().enqueue(object : Callback<List<DtoOutlists>>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<DtoOutlists>>, t: Throwable) {
                    palabra.setText("FAIL")
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<DtoOutlists>>,
                    response: Response<List<DtoOutlists>>
                ) {
                    palabra.setText("WORKS")
                }

            })
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you
[example one with kotlin](https://medium.com/hacktive-devs/making-network-calls-on-android-with-retrofit-kotlins-coroutines-72fd2594184b)

[example 2](https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-networking-with-coroutines-and-retrofit-a2f20dd40a83)

[exanple 3](https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890)